# R is taking longer than usual to load my model into the environment, when should I abandon it

Tags: time, runtime

I am doing mixed linear regression analyses in R using `VariancePartition`. I am using the Kenward-Roger method, which also makes the program take longer to run. It says the model is finished and I am now waiting for it to upload into my environment.

However, I have been waiting for it to upload for ~16 hours now (in total it has been running for ~31 hours since the model itself took ~15 hours). I have run this program before and it usually takes ~12 hours for the model to run and another few hours for it to upload into my environment, but never this long.

I'm not sure at what point I should give up hope, end the session, and try again, as I've already waited almost a day and half for the results.